# Baseboard heat - Installed and then drywall around

Tags: heating, baseboard

I'm in a 1980s house that has baseboard heat. The baseboards are pretty beat up so was going to use a product like neatheat or baseboarder to cover.

When I started looking at the way that they were installed, the heating units themselves are 'sunk' into the wall... like they were installed, and then drywall was hung around them.

Have others seen this? (end caps are not able to be removed...the front piece can be removed on some units, but not others).

Will I be able to use any of these retrofit covers given how the drywall was installed?

Comment: Model #s (if you can find any - possibly under the front piece) and pictures would help.

Comment: @isherwood how to make it look great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that you will be able to use any of the products you mentioned since they both fit over the whole wall mounted baseboard enclosure. Your enclosure is installed as you said, with the drywall set on top of the enclosure so you do not have access to the back of the enclosure. I have only seen this type of installation done once before. I do not know the company that installed them that way but "what a mistake". You will probably be limited to either painting what you have or trying to buy new enclosures from the same manufacturer as those installed. Good luck in your search for a fix.